# How to plot raster file according to its extension

Tags: r

I have `RasterStack`( `b` ) which contains raster layers. I tried to plot it, but my plot looks with extra space (extra coordinates)
I checked my extent: `extent     : 3.916667, 31.58333, 55.33333, 71.16667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`

I used only: `plot(b[[1]])`

If I used
`dput(b[[1]])`, I got it:

```
new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\2000\\bio1.asc", 
    datanotation = "FLT4S", byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, 
    NAchanged = FALSE, nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, 
    toptobottom = TRUE, blockrows = c(rows = 1L), blockcols = c(cols = 664L), 
    driver = "gdal", open = FALSE), data = new(".SingleLayerData", 
    values = logical(0), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = FALSE, 
    fromdisk = TRUE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), haveminmax = FALSE, 
    min = NA, max = NA, band = 1L, unit = "", names = "bio1"), 
    legend = new(".RasterLegend", type = character(0), values = logical(0), 
        color = logical(0), names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), 
    title = character(0), extent = new("Extent", xmin = 3.91666666666667, 
        xmax = 31.5833333333333, ymin = 55.3333333333333, ymax = 71.1666666666666), 
    rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), 
        transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 664L, nrows = 380L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), 
    history = list(), z = list())
```

So, how could I plot my raster with only this extent without extra space?
[image: sample]

Comment: It would be best if you made this reproducible and explained what you did with code and sample data. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith Thank you for your comment, but for sample data it works correctly. I am not sure what is problem of my file

Comment: Try `plot(b[[1]], xlim = c(0, 40))` - but again without a reproducible example it's hard to tell. You can post the structure of your data with `dput(b[[1]])` and edit your question to include the output.

Comment: @jpsmith Thanks. I tried ```plot(b[[1]], xlim = c(0, 40))```, but I got the same result. I included structure of my data.